# How to match copy with parentheses Javascript

Tags: javascript, parentheses

I'm trying to find a specific Product Name on a page, and if this matches then I want to add " - 10% Discount" at the end of this name.

The issue I have is at the end of the Product Name I have in parentheses "(1+1)" how can I include this in the variable `findCopy` so my outcome will be: "Product Name (1+1) - 10% Discount"

```js
var findCopy = 'Product Name';
// The below is what I'm trying to achieve to get
// var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';
var targetThis = document.querySelector('.copy');
targetThis.innerText = targetThis.textContent.replace(new RegExp(findCopy), findCopy + '  - 10% Discount');
```

```html
<p class="copy">Product Name (1+1)</p>
```

Comment: Why use regex? You could [only use CSS](https://jsbin.com/fuyigoh/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Because I'm looking for a specific Product name on the page and all names have the same class, so I would only want to add the 10% discount copy after this product only.

Comment: Why do you use replace? `targetThis.innerText = targetThis.textContent + '  - 10% Discount';` does not work for you?

Comment: The problem is that you are using string replace here and are replacing only the first part of the string with the " - 10% Discount",  why not just have an if statement looking for the product name and if its a match append the 10% to the end?

Comment: Don't think I've worded what I'm trying to achieve correctly. I want to basically find what's in this string" :  var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';  " 

But adding the parentheses in it doesn't work. So is there a way to escape them or to include them in the search for this Product name

Comment: Do you need the "new RegExp" in here, without it, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the product name like `Product Name (1+1)`, so you need to find the tag has the same value and then append it `- 10% Discount`

```js
var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';
        // The below is what I'm trying to achieve to get
        // var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';
var targetThis = [...document.querySelectorAll('.copy')].filter(tag => tag.textContent.includes(findCopy))[0] 

targetThis.innerText = targetThis.textContent + '  - 10% Discount';
```

```html
    <p class="copy">Product Name (1+1)</p>
```

**Update without spread operator**:

```js
        var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';
        // The below is what I'm trying to achieve to get
        // var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';

        var array = document.querySelectorAll('.copy');
        var targetThis;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].textContent.includes(findCopy))
                targetThis = array[i];
        }


        targetThis.innerText = targetThis.textContent + '  - 10% Discount';
```

```html
 <p class="copy">Product Name (1+1)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks how would i do this without the spread operator and arrow function? The online AB testing tool i use doesn't allow this.

Comment: I updated my answer. simply you can use for loop

Answer (score 0):

Heavily based on Alireza Ahmadi solution, but allowing you to change several products at once:

```js
var findCopy = 'Product Name';
        // The below is what I'm trying to achieve to get
        // var findCopy = 'Product Name (1+1)';
var targetThis = [...document.querySelectorAll('.copy')].filter(tag => tag.textContent.includes(findCopy))

targetThis.forEach(el => el.innerText = el.textContent + '  - 10% Discount');
```

```html
<ol>
<li class="copy">Product Name (1+1)</li>
<li class="copy">Product (1+1)</li>
<li class="copy">Product Name</li>
<li class="copy">(1+1) Product Name</li>
<li class="copy">Potato</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether you can use jQuery or not. Here I did a solution using jQuery. Of course it works for multiple

and change them all

HTML:

```
<div class="new">
        <p>
            product Name 1
        </p>
        <p>
            product Name 2
        </p>
        <p>
            product Name 3
        </p>
        <p>
            product Name 1 abcde
        </p>
    </div>
<button onclick="test('product Name 1')">test</button>
```

JS code:

```
function test(string) {         
                $("p:contains('" + string + "')").each(function () {
                    var sHtml = $(this).html();
                    $(this).html(sHtml + " - 10% Discount");
                })
        }
```

Finally it will change the content like below:

product Name 1 - 10% Discount

product Name 2

product Name 3

product Name 1 abcde - 10% Discount